# How to find all elements that contains a value in a specific attribute using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Hi am trying to find all elements that have `display: none` in its `style`
attribute. For example in this div:

```
<div class="w3-col w3-border" id="imgbox1" style="width: 30%; display: none;"><p style="word-wrap: break-word;"><code class="w3-codespan" style="wrap">display:none</code></p>
  <img src="img_5terre.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Italy">
  <p><button class="ws-btn w3-block" onclick="removeElement()">Remove</button></p>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below xpath

```
//*[contains(@style,'display: none')]
```

should represent all the node which are having style as `display none`.

for this specific `div`, you can have `//*` replaced with `//div`. Something like this :

```
//div[contains(@style,'display: none')]
```

**sample code :**

```
disp_none = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@style,'display: none')]")
```

the above list `disp_none`  should contains all the  web elements.

Print the size like this :

```
print(len(disp_none))
```